# How to extract individual words from sentence and match them with words from pos and neg dictionaries in R

Tags: r

I need to create a function in R language, which gonna be able to cut sentence into words and then these words match with words in pos and neg dictionaries. This may resulted into Sentiment Score - for possitive words in sentence is equal to 1 and for negative words in sentence is equal to -1.

```
Product_ID        Sentence        Attribute        SentimentScore
1111111              1            graphics                1
1111111              1            windows                 1
1111111              2            loads                  -1
2222222              1            laptops                -1
2222222              2            design                  1
```

First sentence for product 1111111 may seems like: ... this product... **great graphics**... **works good** on my **windows**.

Eg. Dictionary with possitive words (pos.txt) looks like:
a+
abound
abounds
abundance
abundant
accessable
accessible
acclaim
acclaimed
... and so forth

and dictionary with negative words (neg.txt) looks like:
2-faced
2-faces
abnormal
abolish
abominable
abominably
abominate
abomination
abort
aborted
aborts
... and so forth

I saw a function called score.sentiment at: [gitHub](https://github.com/jeffreybreen/twitter-sentiment-analysis-tutorial-201107/blob/master/R/sentiment.R), but it evaluating all the sentence using of difference between pos and neg words in each sentence. I need something very similar, but for individual words.

I really very appreciate any of your help. Thanks a lot in forward.

Comment: Can you provide the sentences?  THis seems to be a tokenizing and matching task.

Comment: 1st user: Good printer for the money. Wireless setup was surprisingly easy.

Comment: 2nd: Very good laptop! Worth the price too! Amazing and user friendly
3rd: This is a pretty decent laptop/tablet . The picture resolution is amazing!
Good price for what you get. As good as iPad at better price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force approach. Not optimal, as uses too many for loops, but seems to be doing what you need. Hopefully, this should be suitable for your application. You can rearrange things or store results in another variable so that the output is w/o [1] [1] etc.

Code:

```
sent = data.frame(Sentences=c("abundant bad abnormal activity was due to 2-face people","strange exciting activity was due to 2-face people"), user = c(1,2)) 
pos = c("abound" , "abounds", "abundant", "exciting")
neg = c("2-face","abnormal", "strange", "bad", "weird")

words <- matrix(ncol = 2,nrow=8)

words = (str_split(unlist(sent$Sentences)," "))

tmp <- data.frame()
tmn <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(sent)) {
  for (j in 1:length(words)) {
    for (k in 1:length(pos)){
      if (words[[i]][j] == pos[k]) {
        print(paste(i,words[[i]][j],1))
        tmn <- cbind(i,words[[i]][j],1)
        tmp <- rbind(tmp,tmn)
      }
    }
    for (m in 1:length(neg)){
      if (words[[i]][j] == neg[m]) { 
        print(paste(i,words[[i]][j],-1))
        tmn <- cbind(i,words[[i]][j],-1)
        tmp <- rbind(tmp,tmn)
      }
    }  
  }
}

View(tmp)
```

Result:

```
    i   V2         V3
1   1   abundant    1
2   1   bad        -1
3   2   strange    -1
4   2   exciting    1
```

Comment: That's great. Thats exactly what I was looking for. How could I store the results into data frame or matrix nx3?

Comment: Please see above. This is a fast-"invented" solution on a lunch break and is by far not optimal. But it works. Be careful with large datasets, as it uses 3 nested for loops. Should be fine for small ones

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much, you helped me a lot. I'll try to figure out, how it works and then rewrite for large data sets solution, because I need it for big data implementation.

Comment: Something is wrong, because if I run your code, it skips some words in dicrionary:

   sent1 = data.frame(Sentences=c("abundant bad abnormal activity    was due to 2-face people","strange exciting activity was due to great 2-face people"), user = c(1,2)) 
pos1 = c("abound" , "abounds", "abundant", "exciting", "great")
neg1 = c("2-face","abnormal", "strange", "bad", "weird")

It produces only:

[1] "1 abundant 1"
[1] "1 bad -1"
[1] "2 strange -1"
[1] "2 exciting 1"

Comment: Please, could you write a better solution for that.

Comment: Can you post your exact code here? May be there's a typo somewhere

Comment: See below... that's what I tried.

Comment: So, my part of the code worked? Not sure I understood your comment

Comment: No, unfortunately doesn't. If you see print(tmp), so it seems to skip some of the words.

Comment: E.g. great and 2-face is missing.

Comment: Of course! My bad. This should be the correct line: `  for (j in 1:length(words[[i]])) { '

Comment: Yes, it works :-) thanks a lot. Please, do you happen to know, how do I get one word on left and one word on right of matched word?

Comment: Sure thing. If you unlisted the words as above, when you have a matched word say 'words[[i]][2]' ask for words[[i]][1] and [3] - this will be per user [i]

Comment: Please, could you add it into your source code. Lets say we have one word on left and one word on the right side of searched word. This is above my r programming skills.

The best approach would be to write both words into separated columns related to the seached one.

Comment: tmn <- cbind(i,paste(words[[i]][j-1],words[[i]][j],words[[i]][j+1],sep=" "),1)

Comment: Great work, thanks a lot, your job helps me a lot ! !

Answer (score 0):

Will that suit your needs?

```
pos = c("abound" , "abounds", "abundant")
neg = c("2-face","abnormal")

sent = "abundant abnormal activity was due to 2-face people"

p = 0
for (i in 1:length(pos)) {
  if (grepl(pos[i],sent,ignore.case=T) == TRUE) p = p + 1  
}

n = 0
for (i in 1:length(neg)) {
  if (grepl(neg[i],sent,ignore.case=T) == TRUE) n = n + 1  
}

print(p)
print(n)
print(paste("Overall sentence sentiment score = ", p - n))
```

Result: positive 1, negative 2, overall -1

Comment: I need the same output as I showed in table above.

Comment: Cut individual words in sentence and match them to words in dictionary, print them and for pos word 1 and for neg word -1. These values print to another column.

Comment: `words = unlist(str_split(sent," "))
 for (i in 1:length(words)) {
  for (j in 1:length(pos)){
   if (words[i] == pos[j]) print(paste(words[i],1))
  }
  for (k in 1:length(neg)){
    if (words[i] == neg[k]) print(paste(words[i],-1))
  }  
}`

Comment: Result is: [1] "abundant 1"
[1] "abnormal -1"
[1] "2-face -1"

Comment: If I have e.g.
   sent = data.frame(Sentences=c("abundant abnormal activity was due to 2-face people","abundant abnormal activity was due to 2-face people"),
                  user = c(1,2))

Could you cut these words then evaluate and relate to particular user, please... I mean grouping variable would be user.

Comment: Brute force would be to create another outer for statement and loop over user first, then words in sentence for neg and pos for each user. Probably there is a better and more elegant solution that won't need for loops but uses vectorized variables

Comment: How could I do that. Could you please provide me some solution of that, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
sent1 = data.frame(Sentences=c("abundant bad abnormal activity was due to 2- face people","strange exciting activity was due to great 2-face people"), user = c(1,2)) 
pos1 = c("abound" , "abounds", "abundant", "exciting", "great")
neg1 = c("2-face","abnormal", "strange", "bad", "weird")
```

Then I used:

```
words = (str_split(unlist(sent1$Sentences)," "))

tmp <- data.frame()
tmn <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(sent1)) {
   for (j in 1:length(words)) {
    for (k in 1:length(pos1)){
     if (words[[i]][j] == pos1[k]) {
    print(paste(i,words[[i]][j],1))
    tmn <- cbind(i,words[[i]][j],1)
    tmp <- rbind(tmp,tmn)
  }
}
for (m in 1:length(neg1)){
  if (words[[i]][j] == neg1[m]) { 
    print(paste(i,words[[i]][j],-1))
    tmn <- cbind(i,words[[i]][j],-1)
    tmp <- rbind(tmp,tmn)
      }
    }  
  }
 }
```

That resulted into:

```
print(tmp)
  i       V2 V3
1 1 abundant  1
2 1      bad -1
3 2  strange -1
4 2 exciting  1
```

If I do something like that:

```
sent1$Sentences <- as.character(sent1$Sentences)
List <- strsplit(sent1$Sentences, " ")
a <- data.frame(Id=rep(sent1$user, sapply(List, length)),    Words=unlist(List))
a$Words <- as.character(a$Words)
a[a$Words %in% pos1,]
```

resulted into possitive:

```
Id    Words
1 abundant
2 exciting
2    great
```

and negative: 
    a[a$Words %in% neg1,]

```
Id    Words
1      bad
1 abnormal
1   2-face
2  strange
2   2-face
```

But I need to add value 1 for possitive and -1 for negative words.