# POS Tagging & Theme/Pattern Detection in R

Tags: r, themes, text-analysis, pos-tagger

I am new to R and exploring Text Mining. Using the below steps I could get through till stemming however, I would need to do POS tagging and get Text/Theme Pattern. The data that I am using is the customer verbatim. Please help how to proceed further. Most of the articles that I checked do not explain how to do POS tagging for the data in Corpus and I could not find any details on Pattern detection.  Any help would be greatly appreciated...! Thanks in advance,

```
CSVfile = read.csv("Testfortextcsv.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
TestSplit = as.data.frame(sent_detect_nlp(CSVfile$Comment))
colnames(TestSplit)[colnames(TestSplit)=="sent_detect_nlp(CSVfile$Comment)"]<- "Comment"
TestCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(TestSplit$Comment))
TestCorpus = tm_map(TestCorpus, tolower)
TestCorpus = tm_map(TestCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
TestCorpus = tm_map(TestCorpus, removePunctuation)
TestCorpus = tm_map(TestCorpus, removeWords,c("Test",stopwords("SMART"),stopwords("english")))
TestCorpus = tm_map(TestCorpus, stripWhitespace)
TestCorpus = tm_map(TestCorpus, stemDocument)
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(TestCorpus)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
head(d, 10)
```

This I used for getting wordcloud, association and a Barplot.

---

```
WordCloud
----------
set.seed(1234)
wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,max.words=200,random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, colors=brewer.pal(8,
"Dark2"))

Find Frequent Terms
-----------------
findFreqTerms(dtm, lowfreq = 15)

Find Association:
-----------------------
findAssocs(dtm, terms = "account", corlimit = 0.3)

Bar Plot for frequencies
--------------------------
barplot(d[1:10,]$freq, las = 2, names.arg = d[1:10,]$word,col ="lightblue", main ="Most frequent words",ylab = "Word frequencies")
```

Answer (score 3):

The `qdap` package allows you to identify the part of speech of each word in a string.:

```
library(qdap)
s1<-c("Hello World")  
pos(s1)
```

You might find other resources [openNLP](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/openNLP/docs/Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator) and [RTextTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072370/how-to-extract-individual-words-from-sentence-and-match-them-with-words-from-pos) and [another possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610974/extracting-adjnounadjnounnoun-prepadjnounnoun-from-text-jus)

Comment: Thanks @lawyeR . I think it did the POS tagging however, I am not able to export it to a csv file.  Gives me  the following error.                                        Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""pos"" to a data.frame

Comment: Please someone shed some light on Text Theme Pattern/Detection. Thanks in advance